# How to change a url

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to change a url path

Example:

original URL: https://example.com/products.php?category=17

Change to:    https://example.com/drinks/

original URL: https://example.com/products.php?category=10

Change to:    https://example.com/food/

What module should be installed so that the parameters are not presented in the url?

as it should be programmed so that the url has no parameters and the category name is displayed

Comment: Look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), if you must.

Comment: Please review the guidelines on how to write a good post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.href` to get the URL and then you can split it

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = location.href; //You can use this
      var spl = x.split('/'); //to split the url to remove http://www.x.com/
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = spl.slice(3); //get after the link like :index.php?cat=1 bla bla bla
    }
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this answer useful. [How can I do a clean Mod_Rewrite that hides the variable numbers passed in the query string but just shows the titles in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651726/how-can-i-do-a-clean-mod-rewrite-that-hides-the-variable-numbers-passed-in-the-q)

You will need to use mod_rewrite if you're using Apache.  You essentially want Apache to rewrite the URL so the user sees the more attractive URL while the system receives the URL with the query string.